# "sudo apt-get update" packages 404ing in linux mint nadia

Tags: linux-mint, apt-get

In Linux Mint Nadia (Cinnamon), when I run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I got the following set of error; note that I removed `http://`’s due to Super User’s spam filtering.

```
Fetched 173 kB in 13s (12.5 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/nadia/partner/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]

W: Failed to fetch archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/nadia/partner/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]

W: Failed to fetch archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/nadia/partner/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]

W: Failed to fetch dl.google.com/linux/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'non-free/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/nadia/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 199.47.217.170 80]

W: Failed to fetch linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/nadia/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 199.47.217.170 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The same errors also appear in the Update Manager.

Comment: I tried: 

    `sudo rm -fv /var/lib/apt/lists/* &&
    sudo apt-get update`

with no luck. Same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cross-posted this issue to the [Linux Mint forums here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=119348).

The nice folks over there were able to help me with most of the issue.

The `sources.list*` files were auto-configured improperly. The problem is there is no Debian `nadia` repository as viewed here:

```
http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/
```

Open a “Terminal” and edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` like this; using `nano` as an example but feel free to use any text editor you like:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then replace that line, `deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian nadia contrib` with this one in sources list:

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian quantal contrib
```

Save the file and then run this `update` command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Followed by this `upgrade` command:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

In some cases if you switch to 'Server for United Stages' solves your problem. Because, the selected server if not synced with the mains would result in 404s.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't verified [this article](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/62), but check it out and see if modifying the `/etc/apt/sources.list` will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file to make it look like this: (you can edit with gedit as superuser, or vim using `sudo` or however you like it the most)

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ nadia main upstream import
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ quantal partner
deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ quantal free non-free

#deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu quantal-getdeb apps
#deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu quantal-getdeb games
```

then make an update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and the upgrade

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You shouldn't see that error anymore...

Comment: I still get a couple of 404 errors and trying to connect with http://packages.medibuntu.org will take an eternity.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently running Linux Mint 17 (64-bit) and I have had the same problem with this and earlier versions of Ubuntu and Linux Mint (32-bit and 64-bit). What usually works for me is to delete all the files in the /var/lib/apt/lists directory and to delete the `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial` directory by issuing the following commands:

```
cd /var/lib/apt/lists/

sudo rm *

sudo rm -r *

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Usually, this takes care of the 404 errors, but now and then, I have to dig a bit deeper to ferret out the problem. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me: updating the lists to use old-releases.ubuntu.com

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-source-repositories.list
```