# Do online repositories for ubuntu/mint releases disappear after it goes out of support?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, linux-mint, repository, apt

I'm using Linux Mint 13 (Nadia), which is based on Ubuntu 12.04 (Quantal), which went out of support since May 2014. I'm getting 404's when I try to update or install any package. After googling I found this question

["sudo apt-get update" packages 404ing in linux mint nadia](https://superuser.com/questions/517210/sudo-apt-get-update-packages-404ing-in-linux-mint-nadia)

However, this was asked 2 years ago, and the solution does not work. This is my sources.list file.

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ nadia main upstream import 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ quantal partner
#deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ quantal free non-free

#deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu quantal-getdeb apps
#deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu quantal-getdeb games 
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main
```

After visiting archive.ubuntu.com I've noticed that the quantal folder isn't even there.

I realize that Linux Mint Nadia is now unsupported, but unsupported AFAIK means that it doesn't get any security updates, not the complete removal of the online repositories, right? Is there another server I can use for apt?

I'm trying to avoid upgrading because I really do not want to break anything. Past experience tells me that upgrades are nightmares. (I realize I should've stuck to the LTS version but I needed something slightly newer at the time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that, yes, they do remove the online repositories from the official "archive" URL

However, the old things get moved to a new URL: old-releases.ubuntu.com

So the solution is to edit /etc/apt/sources.list, and replace http://archive.ubuntu.com and http://security.ubuntu.com with http://old-releases.ubuntu.com

Source:
https://smyl.es/how-to-fix-ubuntudebian-apt-get-404-not-found-package-repository-errors-saucy-raring-quantal-oneiric-natty/

Took me a while to find the above link :/

Comment: From @roxter: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/dists/precise-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found old-releases.ubuntu.com not working?